# Ruby on Rails Ransack Datetime to date search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, date, ransack

Like carvil I have in my model a datetime for created_at although I wanted the "equals" predicate to compare the created_at and a date (like '2012-09-26').

So I added in my model (in order to add casted attributes and take off the old created_at/update_at/deleted_at :

```
ransacker :created_at do
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("date(items.created_at)")
end

ransacker :updated_at do
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("date(items.updated_at)")
end

ransacker :deleted_at do
    Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("date(items.deleted_at)")
end

# Hide some attributes for advanced search
UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES = ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"]

def self.ransackable_attributes auth_object = nil
    (column_names - UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES) + _ransackers.keys
end
```

But when I confirm the query (created_at equals to '2012-03-24') I have this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for "date(items.created_at)":Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral):
```

Surprisingly, it works with "greater than" and "less than". Only "equals" occurs this error.

I made all of this for all my models and 60% works (the remain 40% occurs this error).

**In the console :**

```
irb(main):232:0> Item.search(:created_at_eq => Date.today.to_s).result
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT :**

I have a default_scope which makes  :
Item(:deleted_at false)

But I don't know why it occurs the error

Comment: It looks like this hasn't been resolved yet: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/34. Did you ever get your issue figured out?

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [second example of Ransack wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers#2-convert-a-user-string-input-and-a-database-datetime-field-to-the-same-date-format-to-find-all-records-with-a-datetime-field-created_at-in-this-example-equal-to-that-date-),

## in the model:

```
ransacker :created_at , type: :date do
  Arel.sql('date(created_at)')
end
```

## in the view:

```
<%= f.search_field(
  :created_at_date_equals, placeholder: t(:date_format)
  ) %>
...
<%= sort_link(@search, :created_at, default_order: :desc) %>
```

## config/initializers/ransack.rb

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'date_equals',
  arel_predicate: 'eq',
  formatter: proc { |v| v.to_date }
  validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
  type: :string
end
```

The new predicate 'date_equals' is added for the date equal search. The ransacker declared with type: :date and get the date from datetime column with Arel

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with this, and came with this:

```
ransacker :created_at, type: :date do
  Arel.sql('date(created_at)')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please changes `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('date(column_name)')` with `Arel.sql('date(column_name)')`.

Your syntax will be ::

```
ransacker :created_at do
    Arel.sql("date(items.created_at)")
end

ransacker :updated_at do
    Arel.sql("date(items.updated_at)")
end

ransacker :deleted_at do
    Arel.sql("date(items.deleted_at)")
end
```

I hove this would be helpful.